# How to get the first X elements?

Tags: jquery

I have a list with a bunch of elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

How can I target the first five `li` elements and add a class to them?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
$("ul > li:lt(5)").addClass("foo");
```

Comment: `:lt(...)` is zero-based so `:lt(5)` would select the first 5 elements

Comment: I am using this with variable but not working $(".print_input_bx:lt(a)").show();

Answer (score 26):

Apart from [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector, you can also use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function.

```
$('li').slice(0, 5).addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 6):

`$('ul li:lt(5)')`

This selects all `<li>`s of `<ul>` whose [index](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) is less than 5 (i.e., 0-4, or the first five)

Comment: i'm no mathematician, but don't you actually mean lt() -- less-than?

Comment: Don't you mean lt(5)?  if its less than then its only 0-3.  Less than or equal to would include the 5th.

Answer (score 2):

for the first five you will want to use

`$('ul li:lt(5)').addClass('first-five');`

Comment: lt is lower than so lower than 4 is 0 1 2 3 (is first 4 )

Answer (score 0):

If you're using $.each method, and you want to use a limit condition into it, i would suggest the following:

```
var $elems = $('ul li');

$.each($elems, function(i){
   var $this = $(this);

   if (i < n) {
      $this.addClass('someClass');
   } else {
      $this.addClass('anotherClass');
   }
});
```