# Remove class from multiple elements with jQuery loop / incrementing ids

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to remove a "hidden" class from a number of subsequent elements, based on a number entered into a field by a user:

I figured I could get the number from the field, then loop through a removeClass instruction to remove the class from the elements in quesiton (the ids relate to the number entered), like this:

[(Alternatively here in jsfiddle form)](https://jsfiddle.net/du2wotbr/)

HTML

```
How many colors? :<input id="color_number" type="number" max="5" min="2" name="color_number" value="2" />

        <p>
            Starting colour:
            <input name="color_0" class="color">
        </p>    

            <p id="c2" class="">
                Next colour:
                <input name="color_1" class="color">
            </p>    
            <p id="c3" class="hidden">
                Next colour:
                <input name="color_2" class="color">
            </p>    
            <p id="c4" class="hidden">
                Next colour:
                <input name="color_3" class="color">
            </p>
            <p id="c5" class="hidden">
                Next colour:
                <input name="color_4" class="color">
            </p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("color_number").keyup(function(){         
    var number = $( "#color_number" ).val();
    var i = number;
    while(i < 5){
        $(["#c"+ i]).removeClass("hidden"); 
        i++;
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {display:none;}
```

**My specific question:**

I want to remove the classes from elements with numbered ids based on the number a user inputs into a field - the method I have tried above does not work, do you know what it is wrong with it and how to make it work? Thank you

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? I am unsure of what you are asking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685758/how-to-get-the-first-x-elements

Comment: I think `$(["#c"+ i])` should be `$("#c"+ i)`

Comment: @Huangism specific question added...

Comment: @Huangism No I tried that also - it doesn't seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/du2wotbr/1/

Comment: o `$("color_number")` is a typo, you want `$("#color_number")` you should have the onLoad option instead of head, is your code inside of doc ready on your local?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some typos here and there and the fiddle isn't setup correctly

https://jsfiddle.net/du2wotbr/2/

```
    $("#color_number").keyup(function () {
        var i = $(this).val();
        while (i < 5) {
            $("#c" + i).removeClass("hidden");
            i++;
        }
    });
```

`$("color_number")` should be `$("#color_number")`

`$(["#c"+ i])` should be `$("#c"+ i)`

On your local, this code should be inside of document ready

As PeterKA's answer, for efficiency, you can look at his answer

Answer (score 1):

@Huangism hit the nail on the head.

However,loops can be quite expensive. Consider using the following approach:

```
    $("#color_number").on('input', function(){
        var i = this.value;
        $('p[id^=c]').addClass('hidden')
        .filter(function() {
            return this.id.slice(1) >= i;
        })
        .removeClass('hidden');
    })
    .trigger('input');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/du2wotbr/5/)

Comment: Very good points, but I wouldn't use `$('p[id^=c]')` since it's very easy of mistake (single letter is too large scale of selection match probability).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem has been clarified by [*@Huangism*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29129277/962734).

I would however change the logic of the code a bit, because in its current form it would cost someone a huge browser lag - as mentioned by [*@PeterKA*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29131479/962734) loops can be expensive (uncontrolled loops, like in the question) .

Next thing is that I would reverse the loop, because now it shows the fields from last to first (Having only two fields visible, they will be `#c1` and `#c5`).

The last thing is the *event*. I would use `input` (as did [*@PeterKA*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29131479/962734)) since it's a field `type="number"` and has its own +/- controls.

```
var inputs = $('input.color:not([name="color_0"])');
$("#color_number").on('input', function(){
    $.isNumeric($(this).val()) || $(this).val('2');
    var number = parseInt($(this).val()),
        l = inputs.length + 1;
    var i = number < l ? number : l;
    inputs.parent().addClass('hidden');
    while(i > 1){
        $("#c"+ i).removeClass("hidden");   
        i--;
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7rxsf8tw/)

Comment: Thank you - valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user $("#color_number") instead of $("color_number")