# Add a div only inside the first three divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a new div inside the first three divs with jquery. Is there a way to do this like :nth-child in css?

My example html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><!-- add div --></div>
  <div class="box"><!-- add div --></div>
  <div class="box"><!-- add div --></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I know something like:

```
<script>
$( ".wrapper .box" ).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );
</script>
```

... but this will add the new div inside all divs ;(.

Comment: How dynamic do you want this? You can add an extra class to the first 3 divs. something like "add_div" and use $( ".wrapper .add_div" ).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first X elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685758/how-to-get-the-first-x-elements)

Comment: Thx for the link, i haven´t found it before - sry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [:lt() selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```js
$(".wrapper .box:lt(3)").append("<div>Hello</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this seemes to be the smartest way - thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to get first 3 elements collection.

```
<script>
$( ".wrapper .box" ).slice(0, 3).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<script>
$( ".wrapper .box" ).slice(0, 3).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );
</script>
```

---

Or with [`:nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-class selector if divs are siblings.

```
<script>
$( ".wrapper .box:nth-child(-n+3)" ).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <!-- add div -->
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $(".wrapper .box:nth-child(-n+3)").append("<div>Hello</div>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a non-jquery version

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

wrapper.children[0].innerHTML = '<div>Hello</div>';
wrapper.children[1].innerHTML = '<div>Hello</div>';
wrapper.children[2].innerHTML = '<div>Hello</div>';
```

or another version of the above would be

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .box'),0,3).forEach(function(div){
   div.innerHTML = '<div>Hello</div>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the first 3 divs with box as a class.

```
for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
$( ".wrapper .box:nth-of-type(" + i + ")" ).append( "<div>Hello</div>" );
}
```

Edit: APAD1 gave you a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`var allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  allBoxes[i].innerHTML = '<div></div>';
}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".wrapper .box:lt(3)").removeClass("d-none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box d-none"></div>
  <div class="box d-none"></div>
  <div class="box d-none"></div>
  <div class="box d-none"></div>
  <div class="box d-none"></div>
  <div class="box d-none "></div>
</div>
```